# How to change iframe src

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

Please bear with me if i'm asking something very basic as I don't know much about coding. I have a stock charting application which has a built-in web browser. I configured this browser to load a html page, which i coded as below, like this mypage.html?symbol=xzy, What i am trying to do here is to capture the submitted html variable, 'symbol' and use its value as part of the url string to load a portion of another third party webpage. I can't figure out what's wrong with my javascript code that is failing to set the value of the 'src' attribute. Any help is most appreciated.

```
<html>
<header>
<script>
document.getElementById('iframe').src = "http://www.asx.com.au/asx/markets/dividends.do?by=asxCodes&asxCodes="+symbol+"&view=all#dividends";
</script>
</header>
<body>
<div id="dividends"></div>
<iframe id="iframe" src="" style="display:hidden;margin-left: -140px; margin-top: -33px"    scrolling="no" frameborder="no" width="398" height="265"></iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The iframe doesn't exist at the time that JavaScript code executes. Put it after the iframe or look into how to wait for the DOM to be ready.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A couple of things: 1) start with performing the function onLoad - that way you know the script will run and popluate the src attribute after the browser renders it, and not before.

2) use a function to get the url value.

```
<html>
<header>
<script>
<!-- source: http://javascriptproductivity.blogspot.com/2013/02/get-url-variables-with-javascript.html -->
function GetUrlValue(VarSearch){
    var SearchString = window.location.search.substring(1);
    var VariableArray = SearchString.split('&');
    for(var i = 0; i < VariableArray.length; i++){
        var KeyValuePair = VariableArray[i].split('=');
        if(KeyValuePair[0] == VarSearch){
        return KeyValuePair[1];
        }
    }
}

function SetContent(){
    var symbol = GetUrlValue('symbol');
document.getElementById('iframe').src = "http://www.asx.com.au/asx/markets/dividends.do?by=asxCodes&asxCodes="+symbol+"&view=all#dividends";
}

</script>
</header>
<body onLoad="SetContent();">
<div id="dividends"></div>
<iframe id="iframe" src="" style="display:hidden;margin-left: -140px; margin-top: -33px"    scrolling="no" frameborder="no" width="398" height="265"></iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot GumbyG. Working beautifully!

Comment: Also want to thank everyone else that tried to help.

Answer (score 1):

try move the `script` after html `DOM`

```
<body>
<div id="dividends"></div>
<iframe id="iframe" src="" style="display:hidden;margin-left: -140px; margin-top: -33px"    scrolling="no" frameborder="no" width="398" height="265"></iframe>
</body>

<script>
document.getElementById('iframe').src = "http://www.asx.com.au/asx/markets/dividends.do?by=asxCodes&asxCodes="+symbol+"&view=all#dividends";
</script>
```

Comment: i tried as suggested and loading this page with url mypage.html?symbol=mms, but page is still blank. mms is a valid stock symbol by the way, should have content shown up.

Comment: @TonyLi did you do like this? http://jsfiddle.net/uzn9pkak/   works fine. maybe you could use firebug checkout what error happened :)

Answer (score 0):

Move the javascript to the bottom of the page AFTER the iframe. You are trying to change an element before it is created. Also do src="about:blank" initially, so it validates.

Comment: Cattla got it. Missed it by 9 secs. :)